# Multiple Datastore writes efficiently to ensure consistency and keep a good user experience

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, latency

We have an application on GAE & Datastore written in Python which allows *admin* users to divide a large sum (*interest*) to multiple *accounts* each has its share allocated and saved in the *share* entity.

It has been noticed that the write operations for admins who have accounts in the order of thousands are quite slow. We are talking 40+ seconds to write and return to user. Which is both, inconvenient and alarmingly close to GAE 60 seconds limit to respond to user request.

The entity models are structured in ancestor based structure, *admin account* is parent to *account*, and *share* has a key property referring to the *account* they belong to and another key property for the *interest* they belong to as well.

***Entities:***

```
admin
  |__account
interest
share
```

All writes are in a cross group transaction function call `@ndb.transactional(xg=True)` to ensure data consistency.

We have tried:

**1. Consecutive `put_multi()` calls**

We have used consecutive put_multi() calls to save each set of entities list:

```
interest.put()
put_multi(accounts_list)
put_multi(shares_list)
...
```

Which at first glance seemed to be a good place to optimize since each call will need to wait to finish before calling the next put_multi() call.

**2. Single `put_multi()` call**

We then tried combining all the lists, and single data entities in a single list and call `put_multi()` once

```
interest.put()
all_data_list = list()
all_data_list.extend(accounts_list)
all_data_list.extend(shares_list)
...

put_multi(all_data_list)
```

The impact of combining all lists was not noticeable when writing to datastore in one call using `put_multi()`

**3. Used `put_multi_async()` for asynchronous write calls**

We then moved to `put_multi_async()` and called each entity list on its own since each call is now asynchronous:

```
interest.put()
put_multi_async(accounts_list)
put_multi_async(shares_list)
...
```

Still performance hasn't been impacted and writes are still slow.

**4. Call `ndb.put_multi()` and `ndb.put_multi_async()` in batches**

We have tried dividing the data lists before calling `ndb.put_multi/_async()` with variable batch sizes (10,15,100,300..etc.). Although docs already mentioned that `put_multi_async()` automatically handles batching

```
batchsize = 100
for i in range(0, len(accounts_list), batchsize):
   ndb.put_multi(accounts_list[i:i+batchsize])
   ndb.put_multi(shares_list[i:i+batchsize])
```

Still no time seems to have been saved, at least not significant enough to be noticeable

5. **tasklet** and batches of **tasklet** calls

We created a tasklet to just save the data, we tried calling it in batches as well, sending the data to it in batches to maximize concurrent writing calls, we also tried different batch sizes, still no progress in terms of write time and returning to user.

```
@ndb.tasklet
def save_entities_tasklet(self, entities):
   yield ndb.put_multi_async(entities, use_memcache=False)
```

We thought of passing this all to a deferred function to run in the background, but it is both, a bit cumbersome since it threw a size error `Exception: The value of property "data" is longer than 1048487 bytes.` [probably the 1 MB task size limit to the data it can handle in the task queue](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas). And inconvenient to the user as they won't be able to see the results right away, and will need to refresh to eventually see the results after the background process has finished.

Increasing the instance class to F4 had little impact as well.

All tests were performed locally and on App Engine.

We unfortunately can not change the data model structure at this point. Our ultimate goal is to minimize the latency to an acceptable user experience level that does not span to 10's of seconds of waiting.

We checked the logs and trace and can confirm it takes that long for saving/loading pages with large number of *accounts* (thousands). Below is an example of the stack trace of one of the save requests that took ~38 seconds to complete..

[image: Trace snapshot]

Full trace example:
[image: Full trace snapshot]

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note about the puts vs commits, is that the puts take ~10% of the time compared to the commit, so changing the order of the puts doesn't change much.  The Commit RPC happens at the end of the transaction (it's an implicit call).  This is because the commit is where the work actually happens.  You can find information about what is happening in the [life of a write](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/understand-reads-writes-scale#understand_life_of_a_write_in) documentation.

To reduce your commit times, you'll want to reduce the size of the update.  This could be done by updating fewer entities, or updating fewer indexed properties.  You probably want to check which properties are indexed on your entities and stop indexing on the properties that are not queried on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, our thoughts were in the same direction, to try to un-index some of the properties not used for querying. But we were wondering if that would affect existing entities that already had their index written or only newer ones? How much of an effect should be expected when we un-index a single property vs. 3~4 properties? Does committing look at the index.yaml or rather the properties themselves that has been set to indexed=False?

Comment: We cleaned up one of the lists indexes by removing unwanted entries in the index.yaml and used ```gcloud datastore indexes cleanup index.yaml``` to apply the changes to App Engine. We checked the Datastore admin indexes and confirm changes have been reflected. We also unindexed a couple of repeated properties that were never used in queries and redeployed. However, the performance haven't changed, we're still at the same commit latency. Is there a wait time that datastore requires for changes to take effect?
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/indexes/cleanup

Comment: For single properties when you set exclude_from_indexes (or indexed=False in ndb) the existing entities are not changed, but future writes delete indexes on existing entities, and new entities will not contain index entries for those properties.

Comment: You may be able to estimate your index fanout through either your ndb models, storage statistics (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/stats), or cloud metrics (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-datastore).

Comment: When we enter new values, the entities are read from the database, updated, then written. Referring to your first comment, I believe this means the newly unindexed properties have deleted those extra indexes. However, as mentioned earlier, after unindexing the unneeded properties, and after removing entries from index.yaml we are not seeing any improvements in the writing time.
We usually check the datastore statistics at https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/databases/-default-/stats

Comment: I added a stack trace snapshot, might shed some light on what's going on. Also noticeable Datastore fetches/puts that occur before the commit, do contribute as well to the overall timing.